# Is it possible to pass a member function to QueueUserAPC?

Tags: c++, callback, member-functions

is there a possibility or a workaround to pass a member function to the Windows API function QueueUserAPC()?

Okay, I could pass a static member function.
But then I won't have full access to local member variables...

So is there a possibility to combine both, passing as member function and full access to non-static member variables?
I tried to work out a solution related to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2227/Member-Threads) but without any success yet.

Hopefully someone got an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of standard pattern to use when having C-style callbacks call your C++ functions.

You create a free function (or static member) that forwards the call ...

```
VOID CALLBACK ForwardTo_MyClass_func( _In_  ULONG_PTR dwParam )
{
    auto* p = (MyClass*)dwParam;
    p->func();
}
```

... and you then set it up by passing the instance pointer as the third parameter to QueueUserAPC:

```
QueueUserAPC( ForwardToMyClass_func, hThread, (ULONG_PTR)pMyClass );
```

If you need further arguments, you will have to create some kind of structure to hold both the instance pointer and the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.
Windows API has a C interface, and therefor cannot handle name mangled signatures, such as C++ member functions. The function you pass must be a C style free function.

By the way, nesting it in a namespace is acceptable, if less scalable:

```
namespace apc_stuff
{
    static MyStruct some_static_data;

    static void __stdcall MyApcFunc(ULONG_PTR data); // PAPCFUNC
};

using namespace apc_stuff;

MyClass::DoSomething(...)
{
    auto my_data = new MyData(...);

    auto data = reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(my_data);

    QueueUserAPC(MyApcFunc, hThread, data)
}

/*static*/ void __stdcall apc_stuff::MyApcFunc(ULONG_PTR data)
{
    auto my_data = reinterpret_cast<MyData *>(data);

    // 
    // use my_data
    // use some_static_data
    // 
}
```